# How to get source code in IntelliJ to use a package that is contained partly in a JAR and partly in a directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have com.a in a jar

and com.b in a directory structure

Right now my source is only recognizing com.a, even though com.b is in the same "libs" folder.

Can someone offer a solution?

Edit: The series of of folders that I imported to the libs folder don't seem to be recognized as a package because it has different folder icons than a package, how do I resolve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to use the com.b class files expanded as a directory structure, rather than a jar, but here's how to do it.

Under your project's `lib` folder, create a new folder named `b`. Move the `com` folder containing the com.b classes under folder `b`. Your folder structure will look like this:

```
myproject/lib/b/com/b/...
```

Now, click *Project Structure*, go to *Libraries*, click *Add new Project Library*, select a *Java* library, and add the directory `lib/b`.

You should now see the com.b classes are recognized by the IDE.

Once again may I suggest that using a jar will give you much better maintainability, rather than unpacking your class files in this fashion.

Here's a link to some reading about [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html), if you feel like going down that route.

Good luck!

Comment: if libs was already a project library, why does this fix it? I think my actual problem was i was trying to make a library from source code instead of the compiled class files.

Comment: For whatever reason, adding `lib` as a project library didn't work for me, perhaps because it contained other things (jars), however using a subdirectory did. glad it is now working for you!